# Win32Exception 32-разрядные процессы не могут получить доступ к 64-разрядному процессу

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Process[] proceses = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (var x in proceses)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (x.MainModule != null)
                    {
                        var desc = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(x.MainModule.FileName);
                        var processname = desc.FileDescription.ToLower();
                        Console.WriteLine(processname);
                    }
                }
                catch(Win32Exception)
                {
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Win 10 x64.Как обойти exception?

Comment: Запусти студию от администратора. У меня все работает.

Comment: @Sergey_73, а если всё-таки ошибку прочитать?

Comment: @Qwertiy, А что тогда помешало написать ответ, если известно из за чего ошибка?

Comment: @Sergey_73, то, что соответствующий ответ уже написали до меня.

Answer (score 3):

В свойствах проекта уберите галочку `Prefer 32-bit` (и убедитесь, что `Platform target` стоит `Any CPU`) или выставьте `Platform target` в `x64`. Тогда ваша программа будет 64-битным процессом и будет иметь доступ ко всем процессам.

Comment: Почему не в Any CPU?

Comment: @Qwertiy по умолчанию стоит Any CPU и Prefer 32-bit, не думал, что автор менял это. Но для ясности добавил в ответ.